# Adding Redirection immediately after Login in ASP.Net Core 2.1 using Identity Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am trying to achieve redirections immediately after Login in a .Net Core 2.1 application using Identity Core.

The redirections are dependent on roles of the logged in user.

I am getting a Null Reference exception.

I read a few stack overflow questions and Git Issues and understood that this is because the user is not stored to the database right after sign in:

```
var result =await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true).Result;
```

I tried the following to retrieve the role of the logged in user:

Method-1:

```
string userRole =_signInManager.Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
```

Method-2:

To determine if a user exists in a given role:

```
User.IsInRole("RoleName")
```

Method-3:

```
_userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user)
```

I am getting a Null reference exception in all cases;
I understand this is because of the request not being completed.

However I don't understand what is going wrong.

Need direction.

This my startup.cs:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings  
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login"; 
                options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout"; 
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied"; 
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{Controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Login - Page  controller of Identity core:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("return path");
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true).Result;
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var usera = User.IsInRole("Role1");
            var users = User.IsInRole("Role2");

            //string userEmail = _signInManager.Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            //string userRole = _signInManager.Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("path1");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
            {
               return RedirectToAction("path2");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Member"))
            {
              return RedirectToAction("path3");
            }
            else
            {
                 return RedirectToPage("/Identity/Account/AccessDenied");
            }
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

   
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the role information after `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` , you can directly query that in database :

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
IList<string> roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```